# I entered date through JDBC, MySQL stores in other form

Tags: java, jdbc, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a text box for entering date in dd-mm-yyyy format now how I can insert this date in MySQL in yyyy-mm-dd format. I writting code for JDBC.

```
String effecteddate=jtextField1.getText();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date myDate = formatter.parse(effecteddate);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
int x=st.executeUpdate("insert into virus values('"+sqlDate+"')");
```

I entered this date **12-05-2010**, Code executed without any error and successful insert message displayed but when I checked in MySQL table I found date in this form- **0017-10-31**

What is problem?

Comment: In your database, what is the datatype of the column you are attempting to insert into? Also you seem to be putting in an invalid date.. right? Shouldn't that be 2010-12-05?

Comment: You entered the date as the string `"12-05-2010"` but used the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`? That appears to be wrong, and I would hope that your code would throw an error on it. Also, *never, ever, ever* use concatenated strings to place values in your SQL. It's just asking for trouble (SQL injection vulnerabilities).

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr Added your observation to my answer.

Comment: The short answer is, don't.  Simple utilise the JDBC drivers capability to deal with a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.TimeStamp` as required by the database, let the database store the value against the appropriate type and simply deal with these types as are.  You only need to worry about the format of the date when you display it to the user

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr My column is of Date type. Your 2nd observation is correct from programmer point of view, but user may enter in dd-mm-yyyy then what to do? This means that I have to restrict users somehow to enter in yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: @cbsecommerce Then **restrict** the user, because your error is that `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("12-05-2010")` returns the date `Sun Oct 31 00:00:00 EST 0017`, aka `0017-10-31`. If you call `setLenient(false)` on the formatter, you'll get the following exception: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12-05-2010"`

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 is that you should use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = "insert into virus values(?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setDate(new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime()));
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Problem 2 is that the date string you gave (`12-05-2010`), does not fit the pattern of your `SimpleDateFormat`, i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd` *(as noted by @Sh4d0wsPlyr)*.
**This is actually the real error.**

To prove that, run the following code:

```
String effecteddate="12-05-2010";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//formatter.setLenient(false);
java.util.Date myDate = formatter.parse(effecteddate);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
System.out.println(sqlDate); // prints: 0017-10-31
```

If you uncomment the `setLenient(false)` call, you get:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12-05-2010"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    . . .
```